# Convert timestamp to date and get HH:MM format

Tags: javascript, json, timestamp, weather-api

I am receiving a JSON object from a the DarkShy weather api, and I want to access the timestamp for each report for a Chart.JS chart where I will display the temperature over day, right now I am stuck in converting the timestamp into a HH:DD:SS format.

This is what I tried

```
// Displays the wrong time according to https://www.epochconverter.com/
var timeofDay = new Date(daily[i].time)
time.push( timeofDay.toTimeString().split(' ')[0] )

// Gets rid off the time, tho It get the date correctly
var timeofDay = new Date(parseFloat(daily[i].time) * 1000)
time.push( timeofDay )

// Returns the wrong date and time
time.push(new Date(daily[i]))
```

Here's how I loop through the JSON file

```
let time = []
let temperatureDaily = []

for(var i=0; i<daily.length; i++){
 // Push the values into the arrays
 var timeofDay = new Date(parseFloat(daily[i].time) * 1000)
                        time.push( timeofDay )

 temperatureDaily.push( (parseFloat(daily[i].temperatureHigh) + parseFloat(daily[i].temperatureLow)) /2)
}
console.log(time);
```

Comment: Is there a problem with using [`timeofDay.getHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours) and [`timeofDay.getMinutes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMinutes)?

Comment: What is the value of `daily[i].time`?

Comment: timeofDay.getHours() is giving me the wrong hours, it should be around 6AM acording to https://www.epochconverter.com/ . Here's the time stamp: 1569304800 and the returned value was: 21

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript?rq=1

Comment: You need to get the UTCHours: `new Date(1569304800 * 1000).getUTCHours()` is `6`. What you're getting is the local hours based on the host timezone offset.

Comment: ` daily[i].time `, here daily is a var where a store the Daily record for the weather report, and I'm accessing the time key.

Comment: Oh, and you don't need *parseFloat*: `new Date(daily[i].time * 1000)` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only interested in the time, and it seems you want UTC, use UTC methods to format the time. Or you can use *toISOString* and trim the bits you don't want, e.g.

```js
let timeValue = 1569304800;
let d = new Date(timeValue * 1000);

// Use toISOString
let hms = d.toISOString().substr(11,8);
console.log(hms);

// Manual format
function toHMS(date){
  let z = n => ('0'+n).slice(-2);
  return `${z(d.getUTCHours())}:${z(d.getUTCMinutes())}:${z(d.getUTCSeconds())}`
}
console.log(toHMS(d));
```

Answer (score -2):

Try `moment.js`.

It gives a lot of date utilities and formatting becomes super easy.